# Kickstart Installation from USB

Tags: usb, kickstart, symlink

My goal is to install Oracle Linux 6.3 from USB. My problem is when I copy DVD media to USB. The symlink file `repodata` is unable to create because the file system is FAT/FAT32. Below is the symlink detail.

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    196 Jun 26  2012 media.repo
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     15 Jun 26  2012 repodata -> Server/repodata
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    108 Jun 26  2012 supportinfo
```

That might be the root cause of my real problem I faced that I stuck at the screen showing "The installation source given by device [sdxx] could not be found . Please check your parameter again." Since it can't find the `repodata` folder (lost symlink of usb).

So, how can I kickstart from USB?

Comment: Read this: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/InstallFromUSBkey

Comment: Thank you SvenW. Using ISO file to the 2ng partition sounds great.

Comment: I would try to use ext3 file system on usb drive first (copy all content from dvd to usb not using ISO file) so I will not have to change the script I've made before. And since most of users use Windows , I would try to find a tool that can format ext3 on usb stick. Then I can create automated script to extract the customize content to usb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know the root cause of this issue. I use source installation as harddrive option (`harddrive --dir=/ --partition=sda4` for ks.cfg or `repo=hd:sdx:/` for boot parameter ) which install from a directory of ISO images on a local drive not the installation tree as I've benn doing.

Reference : http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Kickstart#install

Comment: How did you solve that problem?

Comment: I place the Oracle Linux ISO on the partition used in "repo=hd:sdx:/" instead of copying the whole directory tree from ISO to that partition. This solved the problem.